# Import a package which already ships an index.d.ts

Tags: typescript

For example,

```
yarn add http-status-codes
```

If I import something from that package, as in

```
import { BAD_GATEWAY } from 'http-status-codes';
```

Typescript complains with "Cannot find module http-status-codes". *But* http-status-codes already ships its own `index.d.ts` type definition file.

For some reason, this behavior is **only reproducable with "target": "es6" or above** (no problem with `"es5"` for some reason).

Why can't I use the available typing file? Isn't this the way modern package should work like out of the box, aka **not** requiring an additional `yarn add @types/http-status-codes`? (which does not really exist anyway). What do I have to do to import from a package which includes its type definitions? Why isn't this the default?

Comment: Tried, works for me, the package does ship with a definition so it should work. What `moduleResolution` are you using ? try `"moduleResolution": "node"`

Comment: @TitianCernicova-Dragomir did you specify target es6? I am not using any further ts configuration like moduleResolution.

Comment: Do you specify any module system? If not for `es6` the module system will be `ES2015` which default to the clasic resolution strategy. So you will need `"moduleResolution": "node"` in your tsconfig for it to resolve the module to `node_modules`. See docs https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/module-resolution.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you specify `es6` the module system will default to the native module system for that version of ES (the `ES2015` module system). From the [documentation](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/module-resolution.html):

> There are two possible module resolution strategies: Node and Classic. You can use the --moduleResolution flag to specify the module resolution strategy. If not specified, the default is Classic for --module AMD | System | ES2015 or Node otherwise.

You can read the docs for more information but the `clasic` resolution strategy does not use `node_modules` to find the definitions, while `node` mimics the node way of finding modules (looks in `node_modules` for definitions).

You need to add to your `tsconfig.json` the `moduleResolution` option:

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "moduleResolution": "node",
        "target": "es6",
    }
}
```

This works for `es5`because for `es5` the module system defaults to `"CommonJS"` ([see docs](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/compiler-options.html)) which uses node resolution by default.

Comment: oh wow, I somehow did not see that. It's confusing that with seperate `@types/xyz` definitions, this option is not necessary. Thank you